# Conditional map of Option[Int] pair through a function using scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a pair of `Option[Int]` and want to find the minimum of the two values, if they both exist, otherwise just one of them. Let's say I have a function `minOption`:

```
def minOption(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]): Option[Int]
```

What I want is the following mapping of input to output:

```
(Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(Math.min(a,b))
(Some(a), None) => Some(a)
(None, Some(b)) => Some(b)
(None, None) => None
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I couldn't come up with a different than the obvious way using nested pattern match.

I would assume that this should be trivial to do in `scalaz`, but I am not very familiar with it yet and couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a semigroup for things tagged with Tags.MinVal which selects the minimum val:

```
scala> import scalaz._ ; import Scalaz._ ; import Tags._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import Tags._

scala> MinVal(3).some |+| MinVal(1).some
res0: Option[scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.MinVal]] = Some(1)

scala> MinVal(3).some |+| none[Int @@ MinVal]
res1: Option[scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.MinVal]] = Some(3)

scala> none[Int @@ MinVal] |+| none[Int @@ MinVal]
res2: Option[scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.MinVal]] = None
```

In the above, `Int @@ MinVal` is a type which is a subtype of `Int`, which has been "Tagged" with `MinVal`, which helps select the right semigroup.  `MinVal(x: Int)` returns x with the type `Int @@ MinVal`.   `x.some` is like `Some(x)` except the type is `Option` instead of `Some`, and this helps with type inference (there is a Semigroup for Option, but not for Some),  similarly `none[T]` returns `None`, but its type is `Option[T]` instead of `None` (helpful for the same reasons, there is no Semigroup for None, but there is one for Option)

If there are more than two, perhaps you have a list of these, you can use `suml`:

```
scala> List(MinVal(2).some, None, MinVal(3).some, None, MinVal(1).some).suml
res5: Option[scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.MinVal]] = Some(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need Scalaz for that one: assuming your options are contained in a list (works using varargs as well)

```
 def findMinOpt(li: List[Option[Int]]): Option[Int] =
    {
      val listwithoutOptions = li.flatten
      listwithoutOptions.reduceLeftOption(_ min _)
    }


 def findMinOptVarArgs(li: Option[Int]*): Option[Int] =
    {
      val listwithoutOptions = li.flatten
      listwithoutOptions.reduceLeftOption(_ min _)
    }
```

Comment: you don't need scalaz at all if you're going to reimplement it, thanks for a decent piece of code though

Comment: Since I know that I will only ever have two `Option` values, the `Option` with `Int` tagged with `MinVal` seems the better way to go for me. But thanks anyway.